# How can I preload an embedded YouTube playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, embed, preload

I am trying to preload several videos from a YouTube playlist, which is embedded as a single frame. Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "preload"?
Unfortunately, AFAIK, YouTube API doesn't provide any functionality which allows users to fetch contents manually.